Two different friction coefficients. How contribute?
Let me introduce myself briefly, my name is Rubén and I love physics. This is my first question on the forum, so I hope you can help me, thank you in advance! Here it goes:
Imagine I have an object resting on two areas with different coefficients of friction. For simplicity, let's assume that both areas have the same surface, the object is regular and has a constant surface density, and the normal force on each of the surfaces is half the total. Now suppose we push the object without being able to displace it because we don't reach the maximum static friction force. Since there is a condition of static equilibrium, my question is: what percentage of the total applied force does the friction force of each surface contribute? When the object is moving and assuming equality between static and dynamic coefficients of friction, it is easy to deduce that each force contributes to the total friction in the proportion established by its coefficients of friction, but what about when it is stationary? It seems logical to assume that the same proportionality will be maintained, thinking that this proportion will not change as the applied force increases and we approach the point of the beginning of movement. But what physical law proves that this is the case? Is it? I have the static equilibrium equation with the two friction forces as unknowns, I need another equation to have a compatible determined system, which one is it?
Let's put numbers. Imagine is a block with a surface area of one square meter that weighs 100kg. Half of the bottom surface of the block has a rougher surface finish than the other half, so we have two different friction coefficients. Coefficient 1 is 0.8 and coefficient 2 is 0.4. Each half of the object's mass rests on each half of its surface, so the maximum static frictional force associated with surface 1 is 50x9.8x0.8=392N and the maximum force associated with surface 2 will be 50x9.8x0.4=196N. I understand that to start moving the object we must push it with a force of 392+196 = 588N. But, if I push it with a force of only 100N, which obviously does not move it, what holding force is each of its bottom surface halves exerting? Perhaps 66.6+33.3? That is, proportional to their friction coefficients?
Best regards!

Static friction is similar to the reaction force that keeps the object from sinking through the table. Gravity pushes the object down, and the table pushes up with a force just strong enough to keep the object from sinking.
Static friction is just strong enough to keep the object from moving. In this case, it is just strong enough to keep each half of the object from moving.
The strength of the force on each half depends on details of how you push. It also depends on how elastic the object and table are.
If you push so that all the force is on the left half and none on the right, you would expect all the friction resisting movement to be on the left. But how would you push to make that happen? If the object and table are perfectly rigid, atoms at the point where you push neighbors, who push neighbors, and so on. All the atoms push each other in a way that all forces balance, and nothing moves. But there are lots of ways to arrange the forces so that happens. You can't pick out which way is the right way.
Real objects are deformable at least a little. You can model just an object as atoms connected by springs. For a rigid object, the springs are very stiff and deform very little. But they do deform enough for sound to propagate.
So imagine the object is made of jello. If you push on an edge, the atoms at edge give some. Springs stretch and compress until the forces on all the atoms are $0$.
For the atom you pushed on, you compress the spring to the atom ahead of it. That atoms pushes back. Atoms at the bottom are held by friction forces. So the springs between the bottom and your atoms are stretched. They pull your atom back.
The atom ahead of yours pushes on its neighbor and stretches springs below it. But it wasn't pushed as far as you pushed. So the forces are smaller. For away, there is very little deformation. Forces are small.
For a reasonably rigid object, the distance between atoms changes very little. The forces at the far edge are almost the same as the near edge. You might expect friction forces ahead of where you pushed to be uniformly distributed along the bottom.
Sideways is a little trickier. It isn't necessarily uniform. Imagine a long object where you push forward on one end and backward on the other. This would twist the object. You might expect friction forces to be $0$ in the middle.
If you just pushed on one end of a long object, what would the forces at the other end be? It isn't obvious to me that all points on the bottom would have the same force. I would have to calculate.

Static friction only when the relative velocity between the surfaces which are in contact to each other is = 0, otherwise kinetic friction will act
f_static <= mu_static x Normal
And direction of static friction depends on acceleration (a) of the body in which external force is applied
If a=0, then direction of static friction is opposite to the direction in which body has tendency to move relative to the surface.
If a not equals 0,then we determine friction by the direction of acceleration of the body

The magnitdue of static friction can be determined by drawing proper free body diagram and using newton's law

When the body is moving only kinetic friction acts which is equal to mu_kinetic x Normal, and when body is stationary only static friction acts, both cannot act together on a body at a time

There is no such thing like proportionality, just try different cases on slipping,rolling,relative motion and solve each cases by Free Body Diagram and newtons laws of motion
.You can't generalise this



I'm not sure that this answers the question, which is about the case of static friction - no relative motion. We know that the sum of frictional forces is equal and opposite to the applied force (the "push") but how can we determine the distribution of the frictional forces if the object rests on two different surfaces ?

What I understand is a block's part of the surface is kept on mu1 surface and remaining to mu2 surface, then we first find out the ratio of mu1 is to mu2 and apply the integral to the mu varying with the length... Or imagine half of surface in mu1 another half on mu2 divide the blocks and each block will have mass = total mass/2, and between both blocks Normal will also act as external force then draw the FBD accordingly for each block and find net friction on whole block by finding acclrtion of each blocks and then assume both the blocks as a system and use F_ net=ma  to deduce friction force

Use proper MathJax


For simplicity, let's assume that both areas have the same surface,
the object is regular and has a constant surface density, and the
normal force on each of the surfaces is half the total.

I don't know what you mean by the total normal force. The object exerts a normal force on the supporting surface and the supporting surface exerts an equal and opposite normal force on the object.

what percentage of the total applied force does the friction force of
each surface contribute?

I don't know what you mean by "percentage of the total applied force". The static friction force the surface exerts on the object is equal to and opposes the applied force, for a net force on the object of zero, so it does not accelerate per Newton's 2nd law.

When the object is moving and assuming equality between static and
dynamic coefficients of friction, it is easy to deduce that each force
contributes to the total friction in the proportion established by its
coefficients of friction,

I'm not sure what you mean by "each force contributes to the total friction", but once the maximum possible static friction force is exceeded, the friction becomes kinetic. You can't have static and kinetic friction at the same time.
The coefficient of kinetic friction is almost invariably less than static friction. You can see examples here: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/friction-coefficients-d_778.html  Note that with the sole exception of PTFE all kinetic coefficients are less than static.
Hope this helps.
